# Running MLR using multiple pd.Dataframes: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Fnatic'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run an MLR on LCS data to predict if I were to throw a different team from the LEC into the LCS, how they would do. I am using sklearn to run the regression. When I run the model using the LEC teams data, I get an error. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model as sklm

lcsTeam  = pd.read_csv("LCS_2021_Summer_Team.csv")
#sets your x and y variables
x = lcsTeam[["GP","AGT",'KD','CKPM','GPR','FD%','DRG%','ELD%','FBN%','BN%','LNE%','JNG%','WPM','CWPM','WCPM']]
y = lcsTeam['W']
#next step is to make the regression and fit it to the new averaged data
regr = sklm.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x,y)

#read in LEC data
LEC = pd.read_csv("LEC_2021_Summer_Team.csv")


#next step is to grab the team you want to test
LEC_teamnames = ['Team']
LEC_ = pd.DataFrame(LEC.loc[:, LEC_teamnames])
#LEC_.set_index('Team')

print(LEC_ , ' Choose from one of these teams')
team = (input())

#Use input team name to get the data to test in the LCS
LEC_team = LEC[LEC['Team'] == team]
#check to see if it works
print(LEC_team)
#use MLR

LECWins = regr.predict([LEC_team])
print(team + ' would have ' + LECWins + ' in the LCS this season!')
```

When I run the code, i get the error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Fnatic'. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can only work with numbers in a linear regression. Somewhere in your input or output you have the string `Fnatic`

Comment: It comes from the user input, it then gets used as the "team" variable to pull the data out of the LEC dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If your x contains no_numeric factor variables then you have to change them to numeric variables through one hot encoding. You can try with pandas.get_dummies

Apart from that if your x data frame has all numeric features then you can try this:

```
##  Assuming LEC data frame has same column names as in x    

LEC_team = LEC[LEC['Team'] == team][x.columns] 
LECWins = regr.predict([LEC_team])
```